# Changing background color of keyboard-replaced Picker View

Tags: ios, swift, background, uipickerview

So what I have tried:

```
//1
buildPickers.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.3).CGColor

//2 
buildPickers.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.3).CGColor
```

Now, this works but the transparency won't take effect, because I think there is an extra background view I have not edited as part of what *was* the keyboard.

I have declared the Picker View like this:

```
buildPickers = UIPickerView()
```

and it's used here:

```
buildText.inputView = buildPickers
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use your second option, but without *.CGColor* :

```
buildPickers.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 255/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 0.3)
```

**EDIT:** Since the above didn't help you, have you considered debugging your view using "View UI Hierarchy"?

[image]

[image]

Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: I have tried this, there is some other background object which is causing the opacity parameter to take no proper effect.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some images showing how to debug using "View UI Hierarchy", since I can't paste images in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0

I have also the same problem. I managed to solve it using the method "func numberOfComponents (in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int" like this

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    pickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackDark
    return 1
}
```

It works perfectly